# Light and electromagnetic waves

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light

Light has no charge and electromagnetic waves are created by charged particles, then how does light create an electromagnetic wave?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Light *is* an electromagnetic wave. So these two statements are equivalent:

- "Light has no charge"
- "Electromagnetic waves have no charge"

As are these two:

- "Electromagnetic waves are created by charged particles"
- "Light is created by charged particles"

*Aside: A more precise statement is "light is (or electromagnetic waves are) created by *accelerating* charged particles.*

Therefore, it doesn't make sense to say light "creates" an electromagnetic wave (or vice versa).